# UTF-8 in defaultStreamedContent for excel JSF2

Tags: java, excel, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

First I am converting an uploaded CSV into an XLS with this code.

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    try {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
        String currentLine = null;
        int rowNum = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataFile.getInputstream(), "UTF-8"));
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = currentLine.split(delimiter);
            XSSFRow currentRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
            rowNum++;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have this code to export (download) an xls.

```
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        byte[] data = os.toByteArray();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "application/xls", "non-active.xls");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the  problem is that a file that I have uploaded before looks like this.
[image]

But later I am downloading this xls file with some possible errors added in the last column and it looks like this.

[image]

Is there any possible solution for this issue? thank you in advance.

Comment: What format are you uploading the file in? My guess is it's something like CSV, and you're stuffing up the character encoding when reading from that file. Could it be?

Comment: that is correct iam uploading a csv but later this csv is converted into xls. then Iam downloading it , no changes are applied on the original xls except the last ERRORS column. I updated the convertion from CSV to XLS on the question. I will try to do the same with a ready to upload xls without any convertion, see what happens !

Comment: Are you sure that your input CSV is really in UTF8?

Comment: No iam not. But I tried the same by uploading an XLS and I got no problems. Maybe because you are right about the UTF 8 on csv.